# How do I log in to my online bank account and print the transaction history?

Tags: python, authentication, passwords, mechanize, urllib

I want to log in to my online bank account and print the transaction history.

I'm using an alternative to [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) called [Splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/) because it's much easier to use and more clearly documented.

The code I wrote gives me an error when trying to fill the password form. I can't seem to successfully identify the password form field. Since it doesn't have a "name=" attribute or a css class attribute.

Here's the code:

```
username2 = '***'
password2 = '***'

browser2 = Browser()
browser2.visit('https://mijn.ing.nl/internetbankieren/SesamLoginServlet')
browser2.find_by_css('.firstfield').fill(username2)
browser2.find_by_id('#ewyeszipl').fill(password2)
browser2.click_link_by_text('Inloggen')

url2 = browser2.url
title2 = browser2.title

titlecheck2 = 'Mijn ING Overzicht  - Mijn ING'

print "Stap 2 (Mijn ING):"

if title2 == titlecheck2:
    print('Succeeded')

    print 'The source is:'
    print browser2.html

    browser2.quit()

else:
    print('Failed')

    browser2.quit()
```

The full traceback:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python "/Users/*/Dropbox/Python/Test environment 2.7.3/Splinter.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/*/Dropbox/Python/Test environment 2.7.3/Splinter.py", line 45, in <module>
    browser2.find_by_id('#ewyeszipl').fill_form(password2)
  File "/Users/*/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/splinter/element_list.py", line 73, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'ElementList' object has no attribute 'fill_form'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I don't think this is a wise idea, banks have many security measures - and an automated script might cause alarm, which might result in investigation against you, which could result in criminal charges. The bank *may* have some sort of API - but you should check with your banks policies before you try to do this.

Comment: Reading the error message, it seems like all you need to do is to replace fill_form() by fill() on this line : `browser2.find_by_id('#ewyeszipl').fill_form(password2)`. Does that work ?

Comment: @Inbar Rose this is fully legal here. It will not be a problem. The bank does not have an API.

Comment: @Miklos Aubert, I did, but it still does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Could it be a cookie related problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Splinter's documentation, [you can chain the finding methods](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/finding.html#chaining-find-of-elements). I suggest you try this (I couldn't test it myself!) :

```
browser2.find_by_id('gebruikersnaam').first.find_by_tag('input').fill(username2)
browser2.find_by_id('wachtwoord').first.find_by_tag('input').fill(password2)
```

Notice I also changed the instruction to find the input field for the username, even if you could find it with the `.firstfield` CSS class. I just think it looks a little clearer/cleaner when you select the containing div first and then look for the input field in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot Miklos.

I deleted the hashtags before "gebruikersnaam" and "wachtwoord" to make the code work.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved with the help of Miklos.

Here's the working code:

```
from splinter import *     

# Define the username and password
username2 = '***'
password2 = '***'

# Choose the browser (default is Firefox)
browser2 = Browser()

# Fill in the url
browser2.visit('https://mijn.ing.nl/internetbankieren/SesamLoginServlet')

# Find the username form and fill it with the defined username
browser2.find_by_id('gebruikersnaam').first.find_by_tag('input').fill(username2)

# Find the password form and fill it with the defined password
browser2.find_by_id('wachtwoord').first.find_by_tag('input').fill(password2)

# Find the submit button and click
browser2.find_by_css('.submit').first.click()

# Print the current url
print browser2.url

# Print the current browser title
print browser2.title

# Print the current html source code
print browser2.html
```